# Trying to copy and paste to and from QtableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have a GUI I'm building with PyQt5 and it would be really convenient if I could copy and paste files directly into and from the table widget cells.

The question has already been asked a few times on this site. I tried to apply the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469607/how-to-copy-paste-multiple-items-form-qtableview-created-by-qstandarditemmodel) as my solution.

My `.ui` file imported below contains only a table widget of 10 rows and 5 columns made from qtdesigner and nothing else.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem,QFileSystemModel, QFileDialog,QVBoxLayout,QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

import sys, csv, io


class Main_P(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        loadUi("test_copy&paste.ui",self)
        
        self.tableWidget.installEventFilter(self)
        
        
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
            event.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy)):
            self.copySelection()
            return True
        return super(Main_P, self).eventFilter(source, event)
    
    
    def copySelection(self):
        selection = self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes()
        if selection:
            rows = sorted(index.row() for index in selection)
            columns = sorted(index.column() for index in selection)
            rowcount = rows[-1] - rows[0] + 1
            colcount = columns[-1] - columns[0] + 1
            table = [[''] * colcount for _ in range(rowcount)]
            for index in selection:
                row = index.row() - rows[0]
                column = index.column() - columns[0]
                table[row][column] = index.data()
            stream = io.StringIO()
            csv.writer(stream).writerows(table)
            QtWidgets.qApp.clipboard().setText(stream.getvalue())

        
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_C and (event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier):
            self.copied_cells = sorted(self.tableWidget.selectedIndexes())
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_V and (event.modifiers() & Qt.ControlModifier):
            r = self.tableWidget.currentRow() - self.copied_cells[0].row()
            c = self.tableWidget.currentColumn() - self.copied_cells[0].column()
            for cell in self.copied_cells:
                self.setItem(cell.row() + r, cell.column() + c, QTableWidgetItem(cell.data()))
        
        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main_P()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to follow the answer as best I could even though it was an answer for a Qtableview and I was using a table widget.

It doesn't work and brings up the error `AttributeError: 'Main_P' object has no attribute 'copied_cells'` whenever I press `ctr+V`

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: The copy feature is already implemented in the `eventFilter`, which already returns `True` in the case of the copy shortcut: `keyPressEvent` won't be called in that case, so there's no `copied_cells`.

Comment: Okay, I get that. So is my solution to remove the event filter function?

Comment: You already get a selection in `copySelection`, just make it an instance attribute: instead of `selection = ...` use `self.copied_cells = ...`.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your earlier suggestion. I am now able to copy and paste from one table widget to another. However, I am unable to paste data copied from excel into the tablewidget even though I can copy data from the table widget to excel. Any idea why this is? And any idea how to fix it? Thank you.